# Alternative for getDefinitionByName

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash, flash-cs5

In the past, there was a simple *trick*, to include the [flex](/questions/tagged/flex) `mxmlc` module by adding the following line to the [flash-cs4](/questions/tagged/flash-cs4) makefile:

```
-include-libraries “/absolute/path/to/my/assets/assets.swc”
```

This gave you the ability to use `getDefinitionByName`, an helper function to access the embedded `swc` asset-library (instead of creating hand-written classes all assets).

Unfortunately, this has **stopped** working since [flash-cs4](/questions/tagged/flash-cs4). Does anybody know another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only workaround I have found is to explicitly refer each of asset classes somewhere in the code. You may create dummy class like this:

```
public class AssetsExporter extends Sprite
{   
  public static function export()
  {
    AssetClass1;
    AssetClass2;
    //etc

    trace( "DEBUG AssetsExporter.export()" );
  }
}
```

Specify this class as Document class in Flash IDE, so it will be compiled into the resulting swc. Then in the main code of your application call

```
AssetsExporter.export();
```

After doing this you will be able to use getDefinitionByName().

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to the libraries in the publish settings.

[image: Publish Settings]

(Image from http://wiki.gigya.com/ via Google Images)

By the way, if you use SWC files, you can also do

```
new somepackage.SomeClass();
```

instead of

```
new getDefinitionByName("somepackage.SomeClass")
```

where applicable. This is because SWC files are included at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: how to create it dynamically ?   public function displayLibBitmap(_libraryname:String):void
  { classBmp = new((_libraryname) as Class); ... does not work

Comment: @msec Like I said, where applicable, so not in this case. :) Keep using `getDefinitionByName` for stuff like that.

Comment: i've done that before, man - but i cant get a reference to my swc-classes. why so ? var classBmp:Class = new Class(getDefinitionByName(String(_libraryname)) as Class);

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can change a compiler setting manually, its easy if you are using FlashDevelop as this is very simple to fix.

Right click your included swc from the Project list. Choose options then "include library (complete library)".

..you can now use getDefinitionByName to get an unreferenced class from your swc file.